# Solr AND operator

Tags: solr

I have a problem getting the right results with my SOLR query. Basically, let's say I want all documents in English containing the string "toto".

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr-webservice/query/?q=iso_lang_cd:en&ctnt_val:*toto*`

The problem is that this query sends me all documents in English AND all documents containing toto.

What I need is to get all documents that are in English AND contain toto. How could I achieve this? I'd think this is the standard use of the AND operator...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually OR is the default query operator for Solr and your query is not formatted in such a away as to force an AND operation. In order to achieve the AND behavior you could specify your query in one of the following formats:

```
 +iso_lang_cd:en +ctnt_val:*toto*

 iso_lang_cd:en && ctnt_val:*toto*
```

Or you can optionally pass the `q.op=AND` to force an AND operation. Additionally, you might want to consider using [Filter Queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq), where you could filter on the language. There are some performance improvements with using filter queries, but please refer to the documentation for more details.

```
 q=ctnt_val:*toto*&qf=iso_lang_cd:en
```

Please see The [Standard Query Parser](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser) for more details and a good overview of querying.

Comment: &qf=iso_lang_cd:en should actually be &fq=iso_lang_cd:en